# could not load type MvcApplication on Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, global-asax

I copied my MVC3 Razor website using FTP. However, when I type the URL I get an error:

```
"Could not load type Mynamespace.MvcApplication"
```

and it shows the problem is with Global.asax:

```
 Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MvcPanamaVibes.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

My project runs fine on my computer. I tried by only uploading Global.asax and the rest but got the error. I uploaded Global.asax.cs as well but the problem persists.

If my application is fully compiled and runs fine on my computer, why is it complaining about this? what am I missing?

Comment: are you sure you've uploaded all the dlls for your project?

Comment: Just a quick question, did you upload all the files including the files in the bin\debug | bin\release folders? Additionally have you installed MVC3 onto the server you uploaded to?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem, it was fixed when I rebuilt my MVC project on the server.

Comment: Just exactly how do you rebuild the project on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I was working using IIS Express, and tried with many solutions but none of them worked, after 2 days I found out 1 possible solution:

1. Copy dlls from release output folder, especially [project name].dll
2. Paste to debug output folder then run.